# JQuery search for partial value in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a system that uses local storage to store data. Currently, 3 parts of the system use the local storage, and each system stores it's data differently.

- One part (Part A) stores data using a numerical value as it's key (e.g. 0, 1, 2)
- One part (Part B) stores some data using the value `cor` as it's key
- One part (Part C) stores data using a mixture of a string and a numerical value (e.g. event-1, event-2, event-3)

A feature of the system is that Part A will check to see if there is any stored data in the local storage when the page is first loaded. Part B and Part C are used later.

However, when the page first loads now, it's crashing because I can't figure out how to check if Part C's data is present in local storage. I've tried this method to check for Part C:

```
var eveCheck = val.indexOf('event-');
if(val != 'cor' || eveCheck != 0) {
   //Only Part A does its magic here
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I've also tried this:

```
if(val != 'cor' || val != 'event-*') {
   //Only Part A does its magic here
}
```

But this doesn't work either. What can I do to check for Part C's data? It will always use `event-` at the beginning of the key, but the numerical value will always be different.

**EDIT**
`val` is generated from a for loop. This is earlier in the code:

```
      var bookingList = simpleStorage.index();

      if(bookingList === 0) {

      } else {

        $.each(bookingList, function(i, val){

          if(val != 'cor' || val != 0) {

            var bia = simpleStorage.get(val);

        var eveCheck = val.indexOf('event-');
        if(val != 'cor' || eveCheck != 0) {
           //Only Part A does its magic here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where/How is `val` set?

Comment: This should do: `if(val != 'cor' || val!= 0) {` notice vla!=0

Comment: I've updated the answer with how `val` comes in to it.

Comment: and what is `console.log(val)`? Is it what you expect?

Comment: Yes it is as `val` contains the index of simpleStorage/localstorage.

Comment: Try to avoid using != and ==. Use !== and === instead.

Comment: So you know, `indexOf` returns `-1` when something is not matched.  I can't tell by your logic whether you're using `0` on purpose or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just checking if `val` matches the Part A pattern, but not the Part B or Part C pattern, you could just check if it successfully parses to an integer:

```js
var partAKey = 2;
var partBKey = 'cor';
var partCKey = 'event-5';

function IsKeyPartA (val) {
    return !isNaN(parseInt(val, 10));
}

console.log('Testing part C key: ' + IsKeyPartA(partCKey));
console.log('Testing part B key: ' + IsKeyPartA(partBKey));
console.log('Testing part A key: ' + IsKeyPartA(partAKey));
```

If you wanted to return true for every value that doesn't match the `'cor'` or `'event-'` patterns, you could do the following, though keep in mind that this will match *everything* except strings that match those two exact patterns.

```js
var partAKey = 2;
var partBKey = 'cor';
var partCKey = 'event-5';

function IsKeyPartA (val) {
    //Return true for anything that doesn't match the part B or part C patterns
    return val !== 'cor' && (typeof val !== 'string' || val.indexOf('event-') === -1);
}

console.log('Testing part C key: ' + IsKeyPartA(partCKey));
console.log('Testing part B key: ' + IsKeyPartA(partBKey));
console.log('Testing part A key: ' + IsKeyPartA(partAKey));
```

Comment: Ended up using `if(!isNaN(parseInt(val, 10))` and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party on this one (and the answers posted already are quite excellent), but if you just want to determine if the localStorage object contains any keys that start with "event-", you could always try something simple like the code below.

So you'd basically call it like this:

```
if (localStorageContains('event-')){
  console.log('You have event keys! Hooray!');
} else {
  console.log('No keys yet - time to add some.');
}
```

Obviously, there are some shortcomings with this - it doesn't check if the passed argument is a string or not, for example - but since **you** know what you're looking for, it might be adequate for your needs.

```js
function localStorageContains(searchText){
  var valueToReturn = false;
  for (var i in localStorage){
    if (i.indexOf(searchText) > -1){
      valueToReturn = true;
    } 
  }
  return valueToReturn;
}
```